# Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

After I have added the `_timer` field, I get this error. Before I add `_timer` field, it worked as expected. This is a signalR hub class code.

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed context
> instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance
> that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to
> use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may
> occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or
> wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency
> injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care
> of disposing context instances. Object name: 'xxContext'.

```
public class ProgressHub : Hub
{
    private readonly MyContext _dbContext;
    private readonly Timer _timer;

    public ProgressHub(MyContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;

        _timer = new Timer(async state => await SendProgressUpdate(), null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    }

    public async Task SendProgressUpdate()
    {         
        var totalCompleted = _dbContext.xxx;
        
        // code removed for brevity
    }
}
```

Tried to implement Dispose method but still no avail.

```
public class ProgressHub : Hub
{
    private readonly MyContext _dbContext;
    private Timer _timer;
    private bool _timerDisposed = false;


    public ProgressHub(MyContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;

        _timer = new Timer(async state => await SendProgressUpdate(), null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    }

    public async Task SendProgressUpdate()
    {
        if (_timerDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Error happens here.
        var totalCompleted = _dbContext.xxx;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        _timer?.Dispose();
        _timerDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess would be that you're not stopping the `Timer` after you're finished with that `ProgressHub` object so it keeps on executing that method and accessing the `DbContext` when it shouldn't. You haven't really provided enough information to know whether that actually is the case or not but it seems likely. Make sure that you stop/dispose that `Timer` before the `DbContext` is disposed.

Comment: Scoped services are disposed, when the scope is disposed. I assuming this is in a web project? Where a scope is created and disposed for each request. You should use a producer / consumer queue of some kind to post the request to a background service. Where you can control the lifetime of another service scope.

Comment: In order to do what I said, you should probably implement `IDisposable` in the `ProgressHub` class and stop the `Timer` - whatever that entails - in the `Dispose` method.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, yes it is a web project in which I used dependency injection for my EF Core.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I have tried to implement the Dispose method but still to no avail.

Comment: You've just added a `Dispose` method. You haven't actually implemented `IDisposable`.

Comment: Hi Steve, the error you're encountering is due to the Timer outliving the lifetime of the request and the associated DbContext instance. And hope the answer below could help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing, we should stop using Timer to send updates regularly and instead use other mechanisms, such as IHostedService, so that you can have better control over its life cycle.

**Here is the code for you, you can copy it and use it directly.**

```
// For Program.cs file    
builder.Services.AddHostedService<ProgressBackgroundService>();

// Delete the timer inside your ProgressHub
public class ProgressBackgroundService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IHubContext<ProgressHub> _hubContext;
    private Timer _timer;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ProgressBackgroundService(IHubContext<ProgressHub> hubContext, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(async state => await SendProgressUpdate(), null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task SendProgressUpdate()
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyContext>();

            var totalCompleted = dbContext.xx;

            ///
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my test code, it works fine.

```
using AspCore7_Web_Identity.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SignalRMiddleawre.Hubs;

namespace AspCore7_Web_Identity
{
    public class ProgressBackgroundService : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<MainHub> _hubContext;
        private Timer _timer;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public ProgressBackgroundService(IHubContext<MainHub> hubContext, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _timer = new Timer(async state => await SendProgressUpdate(), null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _timer?.Dispose();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task SendProgressUpdate()
        {
            using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SqlDataContext>();

                var totalCompleted = dbContext.Employee.FirstOrDefault();

                // Broadcast to all clients
                //await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveProgressUpdate", totalCompleted);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There is an exception `System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')'` in this line `using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())`

Comment: Hi @Steve, let me check it, will update soon.

Comment: @Steve Updated！ Please kindly check it, tks~

Comment: Sorry, what should `MainHub` be?

Comment: @Steve It's the hub in my project, you can use ProgressHub to replace it, I  have test the code.

Comment: @Steve The code for the first section I provided can be copied and used directly.

Comment: @Steve Please let me know if it works for you? Thanks ~

Comment: it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what do you put in MainHub actually? Do you mind sharing that code here also?

Comment: Hi @Steve [Just have OnConnectedAsync and OnDisconnectedAsync method.](https://codeshare.io/9OoV97)